# Get textfields horizontal

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have 3 textfields which I have designed as follows. I want them to be horizontal and appear in one line. But they are in vertically 3 lines. Can someone help me?

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
   <legend>The 3 values:</legend>
    <input type="text" id="basic1" value="">
    <input type="text" id="basic2" value="">
    <input type="text" id="basic3"  value="">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place three `EditText`s in a `horizonatl` `LinearLayout`

Comment: I'm using HTML with phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define width of each input field.

```
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>The 3 values:</legend>
        <input style="width:30px; " type="text" id="basic1" value="">
        <input style="width:30px;" type="text" id="basic2" value="">
        <input style="width:30px; "type="text" id="basic3"  value="">
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: i also have tried after that i answered,r u checking it on simulator or on device?

Comment: on emulator.. does it affect?

Comment: i also checked on simulator it works for me u can check with float left

Comment: thank you furqi. I found no way of doing it. Thanks anyway for the support.

Comment: @harsh y?
it works for me buddy on which simulator size resolution r u working?

Comment: @harsh u do 1 thing takes these three fields in table then it will work for u